# How to automate RNDIS Windows drivers installation

Tags: windows, drivers, powershell, device-manager

Since latest Windows 10 versions don't install RNDIS network automatically I need to perform the following procedure after each Windows reboot to connect to my evaluation board:

Device Manager > RNDIS > Update  driver > Browse... > Let me pick... > Microsoft > Remote NDIS compatible device

I couldn't figure out how to do it neither in Powershell nor in pnputil.

Is there a way to automate it?